# How to get a MAC address through MATLAB?

Tags: windows, matlab, ip, ethernet, mac-address

I am going to design a firewall using MATLAB and I need to get Ethernet data like IP, Port and MAC address to write my filter rules.

How do I obtain those?

Answer (score 1):

The MathWorks Staff has answered this [on MATLAB answers](https://mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/91544-how-can-i-get-operating-system-mac-address-for-a-windows-machine-from-matlab-7-14-r2012a):

> Using the output of this command, you can parse the resulting string
> output to get MAC address. For instance:
>
> ```
> [status,result] = dos('getmac');
> mac = result(160:176);
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Since you originally had the [macos](/questions/tagged/macos) tag on your question (before the question was edited), here is a more general solution with error checking that should work on Windows, macOS, and on other UNIX/Linux systems:

```
if ispc
    [status,result] = dos('getmac');
    if status == 0
        mac = result(160:176);
    else
        error('Unable to obtain MAC address.\n%s',result)
    end
elseif isunix
    [status,result] = system('ifconfig en0 | awk ''/ether/ {print $2}''');
    if status == 0
        mac = result(1:end-1); %remove trailing carriage return
    else
        error('Unable to obtain MAC address.\n%s',result);
    end
else
    error('Platform not recognized. Unable to obtain MAC address.');
end
```

For UNIX-based systems (including macOS), the [`system`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/system.html) function is used to call the [`ifconfig`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ifconfig.8.html) and [`awk`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html) commands in the terminal.

Note that for both Windows and UNIX this solution returns the MAC address for the primary Ethernet interface on en0. It's possible that on some systems one may need to change this to en1 or another interface ID depending on what `ifconfig` returns. You can use `ifconfig` via `system` to also obtain IP addresses, port number, etc. on UNIX systems.

Comment: Just FYI: I edited out the macos tag, since I presumed they actually wanted to tag it mac, which is a synonym for macos, rather than mac-address, which is what the question is about. This is better than my answer though; being general is is a lot better